# SharePoint Dates and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am having some troubles dealing with the SharePoint date system, and I was hoping to find some advice here.  The problem I am facing is that every time I use JS to save a new item to my SharePoint list, the date that I pass (simply `yyyy-mm-dd`, no time included) is saved as a day earlier than I intended.  I am almost certain I know why this is- the timezones are different.  While I am at -4, the server is at +1.  I am not familiar enough with how SharePoint receives and stores dates to know how I should proceed to get the dates to work properly.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint datehandling 101 is that it always store the dates in UTC, that is +-0. When using the gui SharePoint automatically translates the time to your local time. Hence, the date and time you get is the UTC version and when saving datetimes through an API you must ensure if the API is localized or not, if it isn't then store the datetime as UTC.